# How to say "Lich" in French?

Tags: traduction, demande-de-mot

What would you call a "[Lich](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lich)" (or undead sorcerer) in French?

Linguee only proposes texts talking about video games, where the names of monsters don't seem to be translated.

Comment: Even on this site [this applies](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645).

Comment: Well, people are usually flexible with typographical rules on SE sites in general, except when the question is precisely about typography.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Il s'agit d'une [*liche*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liche_(cr%C3%A9ature)) ([\liʃ\](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/liche#Nom_commun_3)), nom féminin :

> La liche est, dans la littérature et les jeux fantastiques ou
>   merveilleux, un sorcier mort qui se maintient dans un état de
>   mort-vivance/mort-vie grâce à ses pouvoirs magiques.
>
> [ Wikipédia, [*Liche*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liche_(cr%C3%A9ature)), *Mort-vivant : [Liche](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mort-vivant#Liche)* ]

Le mot est aussi employé en composé, comme dans *dracoliches*, « d'anciens dragons devenus morts-vivants » (Wikipédia). Il s'agirait d'un [emprunt](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liche_(cr%C3%A9ature)#Origine_du_mot) à l'anglais adapté au français ; on peut imaginer que dans l'univers fantastique, une [liche](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/liche) est sans doute rarement très [amicale](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/liche_amie) !

Comment: **mort-vivance** Arghh!! Bon! Je viens d'apprendre un mot. Merci! Note que quand je pense à tout le boxif qu'on à eu fait sur l'**étance** (en soi bien sûr... ;-) ) je me dis que ça doit être du grec ce truc et que... comme de bons auteurs l'ont assuré... *cela ne se lit pas*... ;-)

Comment: Traduire des termes specifiques a une sous-culture impose presque d'embrasser cette dite sous-culture. Bonne aventure a vous.

Comment: @aCOSwt *Vivance* est attesté en ancien français et a d'ailleurs survécu, justement, dans *survivance*...

Comment: @jlliagre : Je dis pas non. Je dis juste que... *nonobstant* vient de me l'apprendre... Note que je ne dis pas que je ne vais pas vite l'oublier aussi... ;-) Sacré Aristote!

Comment: Well I got almost none of that, but I got la liche est un sorcier and wonder what rule just got broke when la changed to un.

Comment: @Joshua I don't think any rule was broken, it's like when you call a man "une personne", or when batman is referred as "la chauve-souris".

Comment: @nonobstantfascisme Thank you!

Comment: @jlliagre Concernant l’attestation en ancien français, je l’ai cherchée pour étoffer un peu ma réponse à [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/32309/13100), mais ne l’ai rencontrée nulle part. Tous les liens de [NGrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vivance&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1700&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cvivance%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bvivance%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BVivance%3B%2Cc0) proposés d’avant le XXe siècle étaient un retour à la ligne après *sur-*. Pas davantage de chance chez [Gallica](https://gallica.bnf.fr).

Comment: @jlliagre Par ailleurs, mes dictionnaires de l’ancien et du moyen français, bien qu’incomplets, demeurent aussi silencieux sur ce terme.

Comment: @GoldenDove You're welcome ! Your question, and others comments, inspired quite a few questions so thanks !

Comment: @Montéedelait Vivance/vivence semble très rare mais apparaît dans quelques œuvres médiévales (cf. http://micmap.org/dicfro/search/dictionnaire-godefroy/vivance ) et aussi le proverbe *N'est si belle vivance qui n'estange (n'empêche de) mourir*.