# L'état (de) mort-vivance/mort-vie/mort-vivant ?

Tags: vocabulaire, traduction, adjectifs, lexique

On a le nom et l'adjectif [*mort-vivant*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/mort-vivant) ; ailleurs on a vu qu'en fiction (la [*liche*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32308)) on a la collocation avec l'*état (de)* et on s'est exprimé de deux manières différentes (*état de mort-vivance, de mort-vie*) sans jamais avoir recours à l'emploi en adjectif *mort-vivant* semble-t-il :

> Un sorcier mort qui se maintient dans *un état (de)
>   mort-vivance/mort-vie/mort-vivant* grâce à ses pouvoirs magiques.

Peut-on comparer ces trois choix ; indiquer si l'un ou l'autre est plus usuel dans ce genre de littérature (merveilleux), généralement en fiction ; dire si l'on emploie *mort-vivant* avec ou sans préposition (*de*) et, le cas échéant, si c'est l'emploi du nom ou de l'adjectif et si dans ce dernier cas le féminin de l'adjectif donnera [*morte-vivante*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mort-vivant) avec un sujet féminin (par ex. *magicienne*) malgré le fait qu'*état* soit masculin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On dit parfois d’une femme enceinte qu’elle est dans un état **intéressant**. Ce genre d’état ne se rencontrant essentiellement que chez des femmes, on déduira que ce n’est pas par calque de la contrepartie masculine qu’*intéressant* est masculin : il s’agit bien d’un accord grammatical avec état. Ceci pourrait sembler clore le débat de *mort-vivant* adjectif, qui s’accorderait avec l’état. Il reste cependant un hic :

- *C’est un sorcier décédé, qui se maintient dans un état mort-vivant grâce à un sortilège puissant.*

...n’est pas exactement élégant, et je ne vois pas qu’un auteur sensé opte pour ce genre de tournure.

*Mort-vivant* nom, qui donnera *morte-vivante* au féminin, ne brille guère non plus, selon moi.

- *C’est un sorcier décédé, qui se maintient dans un état de mort-vivant grâce à un sortilège puissant.*

On parle ici de l’état de mort-vivant comme si tous les morts-vivants partageaient un état unique, des plus récents aux plus décrépits, des plus puissants aux plus misérables, de ceux dont la volonté se limite à chercher de la nourriture à ceux qui travaillent d’arrache-pied à obtenir la vie éternelle. Le merveilleux et le fantastique possèdent une vaste gamme de non-morts, des vampires de l’Europe de l’Est aux zombies haïtiens en passant par les vetālas indiens, les fantômes faméliques du bouddhisme, l’Ankou des Bretons et combien d’autres créatures folkloriques d’un peu partout, en plus de toutes les variétés et variations introduites par les écrivains, dont la créature du docteur Frankenstein et Voldemort, pour ne nommer qu’eux... On n’en ferait pas le tour en un seul jour.

Le véritable point commun de toutes ces créatures est en fait de conjuguer certains états habituellement liés à la mort et certains autres habituellement liés à la vie.

Mais faire appel à l’État de/du mort-vivant avec un grand [É accent aigu](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/21442/13100) demeure vague, car il y en a une multitude, de ces états. C’est comme rappeler que l’état humain consiste à naître, puis à mourir éventuellement.

Il serait mieux venu de simplement invoquer l’état de vie couplé à l’état de mort, l’état de ***mort-vie***, ou de ***mort-vivance***, sans y associer de créature particulière, de façon complètement générale. On pourra apprécier ***mort-vie*** pour sa concision, mais ***mort-vivance***, avec son suffixe [-ance](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ance) me semble plus à même de transmettre spontanément, intuitivement au francophone ou au francophile qu’il s’agit bien de l’état dont on faisait mention au mot précédent.

Comment: Merci ! Une belle analyse qui débutait avec une discussion intéressante ! J'avais pas pensé à l'idée du _sorcier revenu de la mort_ quand j'ai rédigé... peut-être quand dans certains cas ça marche ?

Comment: Ouais... si le sorcier REVIENT de la mort? C'est le cas de Lord Voldemor, après tout, plus ou moins. Une sorte de sortilège à action post-mortem retardée. Mais l’état (de) mort-vivant peut-il être invoqué en ce cas?? Plus de réflexion m'est requise. Merci de prolonger la réflexion. C'est encore et toujours un plaisir de s'attarder aux tenants et aboutissants de vos questions.

Comment: Merci ! Il y a un nombre illimité de questions à poser comme l'histoire de la liche le démontre mais on saisit peu les occasions à mon avis. Je trouve que plus la réputation des utilisateurs augmente, moins ils posent de questions et c'est bien de valeur. Faut dire que le manque d'expertise m'aide sans doute à me poser bien des questions comme l'autre mon prof disait il y a longtemps c'est comme la confiture, quand t'en as peu tu l'étends, la culture. Poser des questions devrait être plus facile, mais en fait je trouve que c'est plus difficile que de répondre en fait. Merci !